# Range and null space of echelon form.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.

Say $R$ is this matrix's echelon form. Is the range of $R$ the same as $A$. How about the null space?

If so, any hints on demonstrations?

Comment: For null space just write down a few equations and see for yourself, you will find out the null space remains the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Nullspace see that there exists a sequence of invertible matrices $$E_1, E_2, ..... E_k$$ such that $$E_1E_2.....E_kA =R$$ so If $Ax=0$ then $EAx=0$ so $Rx=0$.

This can help you see what happens with the first part.

Comment: Indeed, so I would have that null spaces are the same but the range is not, does that make sense? Yet the dimension of the range has to be the same so as to obey rank-nullity theorem.

Answer (score 2):

For the second part, look at the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&2\\3&6\end{pmatrix}$. Then the range of $A$ is spanned by the vector $(1,3)$. But the echelon form of $A$ is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ ad the range of this is spanned by the vector $(1,0)$.

Comment: Appreciate the insight very much, I did this before but I was confused by the dimension of the range and the range itself.

Comment: Are there matrices for which the range and the range of their reduced row echelon form are equal?